# Function with record as argument

Tags: syntax, erlang

I know this is very basic, but it's driving me up a wall:

peercert is defined as:

```
peercert(Socket) -> {ok, Cert} | {error, Reason}

Types

Socket = sslsocket()
Cert = binary()
The peer certificate is returned as a DER-encoded binary. The certificate can be decoded with public_key:pkix_decode_cert/2.
```

Ok, great. sslsocket is defined as -record(sslsocket, {fd = nil, pid = nil})

So I run :

```
New = #sslsocket{pid = Pid},
io:fwrite("~n~npeercert~p~n~n", [ssl:peercert(New)]).
```

But I get an error that

```
no function clause matching ssl:peercert({sslsocket,<0.1277.0>,undefined})
```

So I run it with Pid as an argument and get a similar error:

```
no function clause matching ssl:peercert(<0.1277.0>)
```

I'm totally stumped here. I had it working before, the function says it takes these as arguments...

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: That value looks wrong to me. `pid = ` should be setting the third element of the tuple, not the second. What if you do `ssl:peercert({sslsocket, nil, Pid})`?

Comment: According to documentation: `sslsocket() = opaque()`, so you shouldn't be creating it manually. I looked at the implementation, though, and the only thing I can guess is that you are including a conflicting definition of `sslsocket` somewhere or are running on an Erlang version where `sslsocket` is defined differently (http://erlang.org/doc/apps/ssl/using_ssl.html says "The returned value of the sslsocket is abbreviated with [...] as it can be fairly large and is opaque." which doesn't seem true anymore)

Comment: @Dogbert See my comment on the post below, I attempted that and it didn't throw an error but it hung infinitely

Comment: Actually, @Dogbert, you were right! Feel free to post the answer and I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sslsocket()` type is not a record called `sslsocket`, otherwise it would be written as `#sslsocket{}`. It's a "black box type" (its real type is an implementation detail), but you can obtain it from function `ssl:connect()`.